# Trigger to find contact records who are community users on account

Tags: trigger, community, case, account, case-teams

I need to write a Trigger on the Case Object that lookups the Account field on the Case Object  on and then determines which contacts on that account are community users and assigns them as case team members

Not sure how to determine how a contact is a community user or to assign them as a case team member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community membership is housed in the NetworkMember table, which is basically a junction object between Network (Community) and a User. You can query this table to determine membership in the community but you would first need to obtain the user ids in your trigger. You can do this either from the owner of the case (if your cases are owned by the community members) or query the users associated with the contacts and throw them into a map for later reference.